# SED replace after ignoring

Tags: text-processing, sed

There are many lines in a text file and I would like to change the value `true` to `false` using a one line script.

```
bash-3.2$ grep online test.txt
# online = false --> ONE SHOT import (delete all table contents before importing)
# online = true  --> DIFFERENTIAL import (import without clean the table contents)
online =  true
```

I tried this

```
sed -i.bak '/DIFFERENTIAL\|/ONE SHOT\/!s/online.*/online = false/g'
```

but it gave this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown command: `O'
```

I don't want the first 2 lines to change, only the third `online =  true` to become `online = false`. It can be anywhere in the file but it will match `online =`. So I would want my command to ignore 1 and 2 and change 3 only.

Comment: `\|/ONE SHOT`: looks like you have an extra slash in there.

Comment: sed -i.bak '/DIFFERENTIAL\|ONE SHOT/!s/online.*/online = false/g' test

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking to alter lines starting with `online`, it's perhaps easiest to do this:

```
sed 's/^online\ *=.*/online = false/g'
```

This way, the lines starting with `#` are completely ignored.

An even simpler (but not identical) alternative, suggested by @mikeserv:

```
sed '/^online/s/true/false/'
```

Comment: @mikeserv: Yeah. I don't know for sure how stringent the question's requirement to match `online =` is... I'll integrate your suggestion to my answer; the asker can choose what they prefer.

Comment: I take your point - and it's well made.

Answer (score 1):

Via [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/online =/{c++} c==3{gsub("true","false")}1' test.txt
```

This will match all occurrences of `online =` and increment the counter flag `c++`; When 3 occurrences found `c==3`, then replace the *true* with *false*.

Comment: The OP stated that the pattern can occur anywhere in the file.